# Haskell - The Craft of Functional Programming (exercise 4.3)

Tags: haskell, programming-languages, equals, guard

I have the following question (Haskell - The Craft of Functional Programming):

> Give a definition of the function

```
howManyEqua1 :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
```

> which returns how many of its three arguments are equal, so that

```
howManyEqua1 :: 34 25 36 = 0
howManyEqual :: 34 25 34 = 2
howManyEqual :: 34 34 34 = 3
```

The answer I gave is:

```
howManyEqual :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
howManyEqual    a      b      c
    | a == b && b == c            = 3
    | a == b                      = 2
    | b == c                      = 2
    | a == c                      = 2
    | otherwise                   = 0
```

However, I believe there is a better way to classify it but am not sure of how.

Comment: Why don't I have any answers yet?

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a unicorn. People answer if they feel like it. :)

Comment: ...but when the unicorns do show up they come with balloons. Its amazing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about:

```
howManyEqual a b c
    | a == b && b == c           = 3
    | a /= b && a /= c && b /= c = 0
    | otherwise                  = 2
```

Comment: but what if only one term is equal?

Answer (score 5):

Or:

```
howManyEqual a b c = case length.nub $ [a,b,c] of
    1 -> 3
    2 -> 2
    3 -> 0
```

Update:

Using ryaner's answer as a starting point and luqui's generalization definition, we can also use this one liner and have a general solution with O(n log n) complexity.:

```
howManyEqualG = sum.filter (>1).map length.group.sort
-- Now, specialized to three:
howManyEqual a b c = howManyEqualG [a,b,c]
```

Comment: Aw you beat me. I was about to post that exact same thing! It's unorthodox but an interesting alternative.

Comment: Seems a bit off track for what I need to know, thanks for your answer though!

Comment: Don't know why this got -1.  It's the only one on a track to a general solution for *n* arguments.  +1

Comment: i like it to, but i dont see how this would generalize.  its not even clear what the general question is:  is `howManyEqualN [1,1,1,2,2,3]` equal to 5, 3, what?

Comment: @jon_darkstar Thanks to @luqui and @ryaner we now have a general version using `howManyEqualN [1,1,1,2,2,3] == 5` as per luqui's link definition.

Answer (score 2):

I'm thinking:

```
howManyEqual a b c
  | a == b && b == c           = 3
  | a == b || b == c || a == c = 2
  | otherwise                  = 0
```

I'm not sure if it's better/worse than Sean's.

I might have fewer tests in average due to `||` laziness.

Answer (score 2):

Slightly funny solution:

```
howManyEqual a b c = [0,2,42,3] !! (length $ filter id [a == b, b == c, a == c])
```

**[Edit]**

Shorter:

```
import Data.List
howManyEqual a b c = [42,3,2,0] !! (length $ nub [a,b,c])
```

Comment: Interesting and creative. I like it :)

Answer (score 1):

[Here's a solution for any *n*](http://www.codecatalog.net/280/).

Answer (score 1):

A one liner I can think of that avoids guards:

```
import Data.List

howManyEqual :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
howManyEqual a b c      = maximum $ 0 : (filter (> 1) . map length . group . sort) [a,b,c]
```

This is clearly less efficient though and seems like an overkill of function composition use.

It probably only makes sense to use an algorithm like this if your input is a huge list, where you want to count how many elements are equal the most. This is O(n log n).